# EKS cluster upgrade fail with Kubelet version of Fargate pods must be updated to match cluster version

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, upgrade, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I have an EKS cluster v1.23 with Fargate nodes. Cluster and Nodes are in v1.23.x

```
$ kubectl version --short
Server Version: v1.23.14-eks-ffeb93d
```

Fargate nodes are also in v1.23.14

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                                                  STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
fargate-ip-x-x-x-x.region.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   7m30s   v1.23.14-eks-a1bebd3
fargate-ip-x-x-x-xx.region.compute.internal  Ready    <none>   7m11s   v1.23.14-eks-a1bebd3
```

When I tried to upgrade cluster to 1.24 from AWS console, it gives this error.

```
Kubelet version of Fargate pods must be updated to match cluster version 1.23 before updating cluster version; Please recycle all offending pod replicas
```

What are the other things I have to check?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73550537/14704799

Comment: Thanks. I have already roll out restart everything but it still showing same error when I try to upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fargate nodes are also in v1.23.14

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                                                  STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
fargate-ip-x-x-x-x.region.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   7m30s   v1.23.14-eks-a1bebd3
fargate-ip-x-x-x-xx.region.compute.internal  Ready    <none>   7m11s   v1.23.14-eks-a1bebd3
```

From your question you only have 2 nodes, likely you are running only the coredns. Try `kubectl scale deployment coredns --namespace kube-system --replicas 0` then upgrade. You can scale it back to 2 when the control plane upgrade is completed. Nevertheless, ensure you have selected the correct cluster on the console.

Comment: `kubectl rollout restart deployment coredns --namespace kube-system` would also achieve this aim without turning the service off for a while. You just need to cycle the pod, not have it off while you update.